# ng-hide true if empty filter results?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

While filtering a child select object by a parent select value, I get the results of the filter just as expected using the code bellow.
(filter is based on scope variable $scope.le_form.categories.id)

But I just wanna show the child select, if the filter is not empty:

```
<div ng-show="(labels|filter:labelFilter).length">
    <label>Labels in categories</label>
    <select ng-options="l.label for l in labels | labelFilter: {cats: le_form.categories.id}" ng-model="le_form.product_labels_uid">
        <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
    </select>               
</div>
```

So, my filter works, but I don't this *ng-show* to be true unless the parent id is found on its filter results.

Of course, that condition you see on ng-show works, but it won't hide the div if the filter returns no results. How can I do this?

Comment: Dont this work? `ng-show="(labels|filter:labelFilter).length>0"`

Comment: Tried that, same nothing

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this $watch with a var to hold the filtered results so I can count them:

```
$scope.$watch("le_form.categories_uid.id", function(query){
    $scope.filteredData = $filter("filter")($scope.labels, query);
});
```

Then I can:

> ng-show="filteredData.length"

But the thing is that filter goes through all the object props, so false results were appearing.
In order to be sure about the filteredData contents, I had to copy the logic of my custom filter inside the $watch:

```
$scope.$watch("le_form.categories_uid.id", function(query){
    var arr = [];
    $scope.filteredData = $filter("filter")($scope.labels, query);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredData.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.filteredData[i].categories_uid == query) {
            arr.push($scope.filteredData[i]);
        }
    }
    $scope.filteredData = arr;
});
```

Really have no idea ATM if this is the right way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can hide through twitter bootstrap by default and ng-show="myValue"
You can write $scope.myValue()=function}{
Do your logic here at controller
get filter item...
}

References:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Labels in categories
    
        Select